# Как для одного приложения загрузить 2 язычных apk файла в Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

У меня есть приложение викторина. Одна версия на английском языке, другая на русском. Можно ли для одного приложения в Google Play загружать 2 версии apk файла, 1 для русского языка, др. для английского? Или надо отдельно создавать 2 приложения?

Comment: А в чем проблема сделать поддержку хоть 100 языков в одном приложении?

Comment: Так как загрузить для каждого языка отдельный apk файл?

Comment: Сделать два разных приложения. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html

Answer (score 3):

Приложения идентифицируются по пакету. Вам надо для каждой версии языка свой пакет. Типа `com.example.victorina.ru`, `com.example.victorina.eng` etc

Comment: т.е. нужно создать 2 отдельных приложения?

Comment: @MaxPankov, если вы не хотите/не можете пользоваться стандартными средствами локализации, то да - вам придётся по приложению на каждый язык делать

Comment: если будет 2 приложения, рейтинги будут тоже на 2 разных считаться, никаким образом их прикрутить как-то в общем нельзя?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а можно ли программно добраться и узнать какой язык использует система? там тогда бы просто на таких условиях картинки нужные выводить

Comment: @MaxPankov точно нельзя

Comment: спасибо, попробую с языком системой поработать

Comment: @iFr0z, язык можно узнать через `Locale.getDefault()`, как-то так

Comment: @MaxPankov ну вот и бури в этом направление:)